# php - why showing value of last item from array?

Tags: php, arrays, loops, foreach

Ok, I have this code

```
<?php //getting values
$column1 =  $params->get('param1','');
$column2 =  $params->get('param2','');
$column3 =  $params->get('param3','');
$column4 =  $params->get('param4','');
$column5 =  $params->get('param5','');

//setting array and filter the empty values
$getvalues = array($column1,$column2,$column3,$column4,$column5);
$values = array_filter($getvalues); ?>
```

then I am using these values inside a foreach

```
<?php foreach ( $values as $key=>$value ) : ?>
    <div><?php echo $value; ?></div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

It does the job, but after the loop, it adds the last item's value. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a foeach loop the used $key and $value variables are still alive and holds their last values so i think you are using the $value somewhere else in you code whithout rewriting it's value.

Call unset($value) and unset($key) after the loop and watch the PHP errors i think you will face some if the error reportnig is set to the most strict mode.

Comment: After the loop there is no mention of $key or $value. unset also does not help. How can I stop showing this last value again?

Comment: CORRECTION: unset the $values did the job, you score and I THANK YOU!!